# Connecting C# .Net 3.5 Web service client to AXIS2 service

Tags: web-services, interop, apache-axis

We are using SOAPClient 3.0 for accessing web service.

As SOAPClient is deprecated on .Net Framework as per below URL, we would like to move to .Net web services.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en

When I try to add a web reference using the same URL that I used to connect for SOAP, I am getting following error.

"Please enable REST support in WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml and WEB-INF/web.xml"

Can you please advise on how to proceed.

Regards,
Mugil

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL you are using for "Add Web Reference" ? 
I suspect it is the wrong one.

Try appending ?wsdl to whatever URL you originally tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with a third-party webservice.  As Cheeso suggested, I appended ?wsdl to the end and it came up fine.